# Using Sitecore 10 Dynamic Placeholder via Content Editor

Tags: dynamic-placeholder

Before `Sitecore` had a native `Dynamic Placeholder` implementation, some of the implementations floating around would allow you to use a Dynamic Placeholder as a regular one. Specifically, you could still attach renderings to the Dynamic Placeholder via `Content Editor` by specifying just the placeholder key, without the Rendering's UniqueId or placeholder counter.

I have a use case where content authors prefer to add renderings via the Content Editor in certain situation and the rendering with the Dynamic Placeholder that they are using isn't necessarily going to be repeated on this page type.

The desired result is that `@Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("content")` would be able to recognize both `"content-{XXXGUIDXXX}-0" *and* just "content"`.

Is there a good solution for this in SC10?

Answer (score 5):

OOTB it is not possible adding dynamic placeholder via Content editor. We can add dynamic placeholder only by experience editor.

Comment: Thanks, that's the problem that I am trying to solve.